# Cannot post to twitter via Twitter-OAuth-iPhone in a NSThread

Tags: iphone, nsthread, twitter-oauth

I recently started using Ben Gottlieb's [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) class to post status updates in app.  I have successfully done so, when executed on the application's main thread.  But, when I throw it in a "NSThread detachNewThreadSelector" the post never makes it to twitter.  It processes fine and I get a proper [connection identifier], but the results never make it on twitter.  Any idea how I can get this to run in a thread without bringing it back to the main thread?

**Code added**
Tweet method

```
-(void)tweet{  
if([_engine isAuthorized]){
    [_engine sendUpdate:@"Tweeting"];  
}  
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(tweet) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Does work (from main app):

```
[self tweet];
```

Does work (from within a thread):

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(tweet) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: There's no reason you can't do that with an NSThread. Perhaps you could post the relevant code?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code.